# Rotating group of bodies in pymunk

Tags: python, pygame, simulation, chipmunk, pymunk

I want to make a 2D grasping hand in pymunk, which can rotate, move up/down and to the sides and clench or extend its fingers, basically, the hand looks like 'U' letter. I tried to do it by making 3 separate bodies (palm, left finger, right finger) and connect it by some joints (PinJoint and probably some different one). Problem is when I rotate the palm(by changing angle or angular_velocity), fingers start to act strangely. Also, I want to make fingers extendable/clenchable too.

Here is my gripper code:

```
class Gripper(pymunk.Body):

def __init__(self, space):
    super().__init__(2**8, pymunk.inf)
    self.position = (100, 25)

    palm = pymunk.Segment(self, (-7, 0), (7, 0), 2)

    # Left gripper side
    self.l_phalanx_body = pymunk.Body(2**8, pymunk.inf)
    self.l_phalanx_body.position = (self.position.x - 7, self.position.y)

    phalanx_l1 = pymunk.Segment(self.l_phalanx_body, (0, 0), (0, 16), 2)
    phalanx_l2 = pymunk.Segment(self.l_phalanx_body, (0, 16), (4, 16), 2)

    l_joint = pymunk.PinJoint(self, self.l_phalanx_body, (-7, 0))
    # l_rot_joint = pymunk.DampedRotarySpring(self, self.l_phalanx_body, 0, 1, 1)

    # Right gripper side
    self.r_phalanx_body = pymunk.Body(2**8, pymunk.inf)
    self.r_phalanx_body.position = (self.position.x + 7, self.position.y)

    phalanx_r1 = pymunk.Segment(self.r_phalanx_body, (0, 0), (0, 16), 2)
    phalanx_r2 = pymunk.Segment(self.r_phalanx_body, (0, 16), (-4, 16), 2)

    r_joint = pymunk.PinJoint(self, self.r_phalanx_body, (7, 0), (0, 0))

    shape_filter = pymunk.ShapeFilter(group=1)
    palm.filter = shape_filter
    phalanx_l1.filter = shape_filter
    phalanx_l2.filter = shape_filter
    phalanx_r1.filter = shape_filter
    phalanx_r2.filter = shape_filter

    space.add(
        self, palm,
        l_joint,
        # l_rot_joint,
        self.l_phalanx_body,
        phalanx_l1, phalanx_l2,
        r_joint, self.r_phalanx_body,
        phalanx_r1, phalanx_r2,
        )
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you made a (ver small) runnable example, that way its easier to understand whats wrong and also test any suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you rotate by setting the velocity directly. You can try to instead rotate with a SimpleMotor constraint between the palm body and a space static body. Here is the api docs of SimpleMotor: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.constraint.html#pymunk.constraint.SimpleMotor